# In SAS is there a fractional response procedure

Tags: sas, regression, beta

In SAS is there a fractional response procedure

```
   proc glimmix data=damage;
    model y = lconc / dist=beta link=logit solution;
    output out=gmxout pred(ilink)=gpredy lcl(ilink)=lower ucl(ilink)=upper;
    run;
```

In SAS is there a fractional response procedure

Comment: glimmix is the procedure that does it. https://support.sas.com/kb/56/992.html